# What does active column represent in celery flower

Tags: python, celery, flower

Can anyone guide me that what does active column is representing here exactly?
My current understanding is that for example for celery@worker45, it is showing that 5 threads of this worker are active at the moment. See screenshot for reference

Also, one of my workers is going offline for a second again and again. What does this mean?

[image: see screenshot for reference]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Active" column in Flower's dashboard gives you the same numbers [inspect active](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#commands) command gives (try `celery -A your.celery.app inspect active`). Basically, number of tasks currently running on that particular node.

When a worker disappears on Flower's dashboard, it means it failed to send the heartbeat signal back to Flower. This is typically due to some networking issues.